# postgresql regroup consecutive hour

Tags: postgresql, hour

the idea is to group the free hours to offer appointments to future customers

i have 3 tables

**hour_dimension** which includes working hours

```
select hour from hour_dimension

|hour   |
|-------|
|09:00  |
|09:30  |
|10:00  |
|10:30  |
|11:00  |
|11:30  |
|12:00  |
|14:00  |
|14:30  |
|15:00  |
|15:30  |
|16:00  |
|16:30  |
|17:00  |
|17:30  |
|18:00  |
|18:30  |
|19:00  |
|19:30  |
|20:00  |
```

**event** that makes the relationship between a customer and an appointment

```
|id |commentaire|client_id  |sms|state_id   |
---------------------------------------------
|463|           |308        |1  |1          |
|464|           |308        |1  |1          |
|465|           |308        |1  |1          |
```

**rdv** that contains customer appointments (just for info event.id = rdv.id)

```
|id |date       |heure_debut|heure_fin  |
-----------------------------------------
|463|2018-02-15 |09:30      |11:00      |
|464|2018-02-15 |14:00      |16:00      |
|465|2018-02-15 |17:00      |18:00      |
```

now, I execute this query to find the free hours :

```
select h.hour, heure_debut as begin_hour, heure_fin as end_hour
FROM hour_dimension h

left join 
( select * from rdv r 
left join event e ON (r.id = e.id)
where r.date = '2018-02-15' and e.state_id IN (1,2) )_A
ON (h.hour> heure_debut and h.hour < heure_fin)
```

**result** : 
[pic.PNG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCQeb.png) I surrounded the free hours.

now, I would like to group the free hours and have this result :

```
|begin| end |duration|
|-----+-----+--------|
|09:00|09:30| 30mins |
|11:00|12:00| 60mins | 12:00 - 14:00 break time
|16:00|17:00| 60mins |
|18:00|20:00| 120mins|
```

Answer (score 0):

Best "intermediate" solution I was able to find on the fly was [this](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/42d07/6/0) fiddle.

My guess is you'll need a function to finally produce the result u are aiming for.

If u take this fiddles intermediate result, feed/include it to/in a function, eliminating all the rows with the same start as the previous rows end, saving them as temp_begin and temp_end and call

```
EXTRACT(epoch FROM 
    to_timestamp(temp_end,  'HH24:MI') 
  - to_timestamp(temp_begin,'HH24:MI')
)/60
```

on those temp variables you should be able get what you are looking for